Ethernet cable speed differs if connected one way or the other way
I have an issue and i don't know what's wrong.
I have an ethernet cable Cat 7-A and when using it on my desktop computer I only get 100 mbps  connection.
When I plug it into a brand new laptop, if I connect it one way I get up to 100 mbps but if I do plug it the opposite way I get 1Gbps.
Also on my desktop computer if I plug a cat5 cable labelled with 10 - 100 mbps I get up to 1gbps.
What can be causing the cable speed to change between one way connection or the other way ?
Edit:  Cable is using T568B standard

Is it a bought cable or was it constructed? Sounds like the cable has a breach somewhere that sometimes connects, sometimes don't. And is it a new or old cable? You only need 4 good wires for a 100 mbit connection, the other 4 wires are for the gigabit.

I did bought the cable and added the connectors.
But if it were a build issue like a cable broken or not connected, then  why it does always reach 1gbps connected in one way and 100mbps connected the other way ?

What is the “opposite way” an Ethernet cable can only be inserted one way. Do you mean you get one speed if you connect Side A vs Side B?

Could be partially damaged connectors. If the crimp job on one end of the cord was poor, leaving the teeth/pins in bad positions, and the wires in the female port on the PC were a little bent or not very stiff/springy, it could cause one male-female connector mating to be flaky, whereas another pairing could work fine.

is the cable straight or is it crossover?

So its a constructed cable then. Most likely one of the connectors has the pin touching the wire, but not all the way through, so moving the cable may disconnect that pin from the cable in such way that the speed is going to vary. For 1Gbps you need a perfect connection, and you obviously don't have one. My advise, cut both ends, and recrimp the connectors again.

Getting crimped connectors right can take some practice. It seems you need more, and a magnifying glass to try to see where it went wrong. Unless you have a real need to do that, it's going to be cheaper to get ready-made cables. N.B. If Cat 5e is all that is required, there's no point spending extra.

Well since most answers are related to the connectors, i just did cut the cable and addded new connectors and now it works perfectly.
So thanks everyone for the solution answering that it must be connector-related issue, you made my day <3
